# Backbone.js collection doesn't listen model change event

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

I've just started using backbone.js to create a spa. I'm trying to make a books collection listen to model change but nothing happens. This is the model and collection:

```
var Book = Backbone.Model.extend({

  idAttribute: 'id',

  defaults: {
    id: null,
    title: '',
    author: '',
    completed: false
  }

});

var BooksCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

  model: Book,

  url: 'books',

  initialize: function() {
    this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.debug);
  },

  debug: function () {
    console.log('something happened !!!');
  }

});
```

This is the view:

```
var BookView = Backbone.View.extend({

    template: _.template($('#viewBook').html()),

    events: {
        "click #save": "bookSave"
    },

    initialize: function() {
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
    },

    render: function() {
        $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    },

    bookSave: function() {
        this.model.set({author: "nobody"});
    }

});
```

When I click on the <kbd>#save</kbd> button the author is changed but nothing is logged. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Using save() it sends a request to server. I only want to change the collection model attribute value. Can't collections listen to attribute changes ? Can they only listen to sync events ?

Comment: are you sure the view and model are referencing the same model? you can explicitly create a new Model and pass it to the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Events from models automatically bubbles up to the collection, so you can listen to model changes directly like this:

```
// in the collection
initialize: function() {
    this.listenTo(this, 'change', this.debug);
},
```